# How To Limit The Length of Text in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

What i Need:

- how to calculate the length of four companies, and restrict on length so that only four companies are view on dashboard.

  Our Mid Level Transport System ,

  Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 05) ,

  In-Line Amplification Systems

  Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 03) .
- i want that consider there are four  companies  name if  5 is added then it woudn"t reflect.

Here is what i have tried.

```
           {% set foo = item.Product_Name|split(',') %}
            {% for i in  foo|slice(0, 5) %}
            {{ i|length > 50 ? i|slice(0, 100) ~ ' ' : i  }}
                     {% if(loop.last)< 5 %}
                     ,
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Write Your own Symfony2 Twig filter which will use `substr` to reduce text

Comment: consider there there data in four line line 1, line 2, line 3, line4 and and if  new data is added in line five then it would show (empty) or say(....) i need to restrict data in div .

Comment: So maybe You need to use `ellipsis` in you `css`

Comment: i just  want code that in twig where im wrong on using this code{{ i[:50] ~ '..' }}. o/p Our Mid Level Transport System.. , Intelligent Ethernet Access System (Ieas 05).. ,  but i want to check if  data is more then 4 line then only (..)appear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about...

```
{% set names = item.Product_Name|split(',') %}
{% set maxNames = 4 %}

<ul>
    {% for name in names|slice(0, maxNames) %}
        <li>
            {{ name|length < 50 ? name : name|slice(0, 50) ~ '...' }}
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li>No Results</li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if names|length > maxNames %}
        <li>More Results Available</li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

If not then I'm clearly not too sure about what you are actually after.

Also, what is the need for the `,`'s in between each name?

If you are wanting something more complex then there is the possibility it should be handled outside of the template and in some kind of twig function.

Comment: i want  consider  line 1, line 2, line 3, line4  if line 5 occurs then it wouldn"t display data in next 5 line that i want hope you understand

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you want a bit better. Possibly with some sort of visual aid rather than in text/anecdotal form. Also you talk about companies in your question but nothing in your "have tried" says anything about companies. Maybe having those variables reflect what you mean would enable people to make more sense of your request.

Comment: here is the  url : http://www.picresize.com/popup.html?images/rsz_screenshot_from_2014-08-20_172053.png  i just want stop data being visulized after 4 line in div

Comment: you could see int(22) Ethernet Access System is coming in 5 line i want code that i would not visible after 4 line that iwant

Comment: how could i count no of line in div if (no line >4) no data shown else

Comment: I meant an image of what you want. Provide the original data (or some kind of sample of it) and the image of you you want it to be displayed.

Comment: i want to count the no charcter in string  and check data should be more then 4 line , as you would see in image  data is ethrnet acces is coming 5 line  i want data should be in 4 line